# Error using Zeros in Matlab while training

Tags: matlab, matrix, machine-learning, neural-network

I am Trying to train my Neural Network using `vInputs` and `vTargets` to create a model `net`
But I keep getting this irritating Error no matter what I try to correct in my code:

**ERROR:** *Error using zeros.Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded.*

I dont find any such big data created by my code and I have a RAM of 4GB

I have 230 images which I need to classify in 3 parts `'Sedan', 'SUV', 'Hatchback'`

`image size [15x26]`

I used this code to convert single image's features extracted by `gabor filter` to `Feature Vector`

```
function IMVECTOR = im2vec (img)
load Gabor;
img = adapthisteq(img); 
Features75x208 = cell(5,8);
for s = 1:5
    for j = 1:8
        Features75x208{s,j} = mminmax(abs(ifft2(G{s,j}.*fft2(double(img),32,32),15,26)));
    end
end
Features25x70 = cell2mat(Features75x208);
Features25x70 (3:3:end,:)=[];
Features25x70 (2:2:end,:)=[];
Features25x70 (:,3:3:end)=[];
Features25x70 (:,2:2:end)=[];
IMVECTOR = reshape (Features25x70,[1750 1]);
```

Now after the feature vector is created I made `vInputs` using same function for 230 images.
Thus I got
1. `vInputs=[1750x230].`

2. `vTargets=[4x230].`

But whenever I run the `Project` I get error in `function`.

```
function net = create_pr_net(inputs,targets)
%CREATE_PR_NET Creates and trains a pattern recognition neural network.
% Create Network
numHiddenNeurons = 35;  
net = newpr(inputs,targets,numHiddenNeurons);
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;  
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;  
net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100; 
% Train and Apply Network
[net,tr] = train(net,inputs,targets);% <== ERROR OCCURS HERE<==
outputs = sim(net,inputs);
% Plot
plotperf(tr);
plotconfusion(targets,outputs);
save net net
```

Here is the complete Error:

```
Error using zeros
Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded.

Error in nnMex2.codeHints (line 117)
hints.TEMP =
zeros(1,ceil(tempSize/8),'double');

Error in nncalc.setup2 (line 13)
  calcHints = calcMode.codeHints(calcHints);

Error in network/train (line 306)
  [calcLib,calcNet] = nncalc.setup2(calcMode,calcNet,calcData,calcHints);

Error in create_pr_net (line 14)
[net,tr] = train(net,inputs,targets);

Error in executeMe (line 22)
  net=create_pr_net(vInputs,vTargets);
```

Please Help me and ask me if I missed anything and need to specify some more details.

value of `tempSize`:

[image: tempSize]

**EDIT:** Well I figured it out that as I am using 32bit system so I can address a maximum of 
`2^32 = 4.294967e+09` at a time.
While if I was using 64bit I could be able to address about 
`2^64 = 9.22337e+18` address at a time.
So can you guys give me some idea about how to make it work on my system.

Comment: What is the value of `tempSize`? Type `dbstop if error` and run again.  You will be at a debugging command prompt where you can check.

Comment: HDD space has nothing to do with the error. If at all, its the RAM space which matters

Comment: Yeah!!!! I just went in a flow...I know the difference between RAM and Hard Disk [I will correct that]

Comment: @chappjc I am attaching a image of  `tempSize` value.

Comment: Wowwww, that's a problem.  Work backwards (inspect variables above that line) or set an earlier breakpoint to figure out where that is getting so huge.

Comment: ok let me check that....

Comment: What I figured out is `Weights = 61393`,`maxDelayedElements=1750`,`sizeOfDouble=8` and `B=32` they all multiply to give a big value...How can I decrease number of Weights.